# See all correctly and incorrectly identified images when training on the mnist dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to find a way to visualize which numbers in the mnist dataset a model was able to correctly identify and which ones it wasn't. 
What I can't seem to find is if such a visualization is possible in tensorboard or if I would need to use/create something else to achieve it.

I'm currently working from the [basic tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) provided for tensorflow 2.0 with tensorboard added.

```
import datetime
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

log_dir="logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          epochs=5,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: You need to provide code which you have tried so far

Comment: Your question seems vague or is missing essential details/code. Please look over [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I think I might have found the answer to my question; it looks like the 'What-If tool' will display the images that the model identified correctly and the ones it identified incorrectly. I can't post this as answer to my question yet though because I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the what-if tool is what I was looking for, it allows you to visually sort testing data depending on whether it was [correctly or incorrectly identified by the model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrxiW.jpg)

If you want to test it out [here](https://pair-code.github.io/what-if-tool/age.html) is their demo that I used to get the above image and they have multiple other demos on the tools [site](https://pair-code.github.io/what-if-tool/index.html#demos).